# SO's "We are offline" page has nested IFRAMES (Inception-style). Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, offline

[image: screenshot]
Click to enlarge.

Why are the IFRAME elements nested? Is this a bug?

Comment: Only four iframes? They have to go deeper.

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  The servers are currently `offline` stuck in an infinite `iframe` loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because the `<iframe>` loads the offline page specific for the site you're visiting (or sketchy for beta sites).  However, in cases like today we took our entire network offline, including sstatic.net, so the offline pages the top level page load's in its `<iframe>` were...itself, being served by the load balancer, loading another frame *again*.

I added a check for this, and we'll print out a nice message instead of continually loading nested frames in the future.